# Route only certain IP range with VPN connection

Tags: macos, networking, routes, vpn

We are using `FortiClient` to connect to one of our client's VPN. Unfortunately, `FortiClient` is routing **all the traffic over VPN as default**.

We have found a way around it, for Linux. After connecting with VPN we run:

```
sudo route del default ppp0
sudo route add -net 172.20.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev ppp0
```

And now, only the addresses starting with `172.20.x.x` are resolved over VPN connection.

Now, I am using `FortiClient 5.4` on `Mac OS X 10.11.6` and I am trying to remake the above to work on `Mac OS X`. Basically I have problems even with the first step. I have tried:

```
sudo route delete -net default -ifp ppp0
```

But the routing still does not work expected. Easily to test, because there is no Internet connection behind the VPN - I can not browse/ping any website :-).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related sites http://serverfault.com OR http://SuperUser.com OR even http://apple.stackexchange.com (Ask Different).. Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. You may also want to read Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/728702/how-to-get-forticlient-working-in-osx-el-capitan/728707#728707) to help me out and it turned out I needed one extra command.

Basically the working solution for `Mac OS X 10.11.6` goes as follows:

```
sudo route delete -net default -interface ppp0
sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 -interface en0
sudo route add -net 172.20.0.0 -netmask 255.255.0.0 -interface ppp0
```

Which basically means:

1. Delete default route on interface `ppp0` which was set by `FortiClient`
2. Add default route for every IP on your default interface (for me `en0`)
3. Route the specific IP range through `ppp0` (FortiClient) interface.

`Linux` equivalent, as mentioned in the question, is:

```
sudo route del default ppp0
sudo route add -net 172.20.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev ppp0
```

So you actually skip the step #2.

Not that hard in the end.

Comment: What would be the equivalent on Windows? It seems Forticlient monitors route changes and always adds a default route with a lower metric.

Answer (score 0):

Beside Atais [First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39612554/7508077), For new `ip` command here is the solution.

```
sudo ip r del default

# second address is Gateway
sudo ip r add 192.168.5.0/24 via 192.168.138.224
```

First one will remove default rote which is set to my **ppp0 VPN** connection,
And then second one, add route only for specific IP rage to company Gateway.